# Calling a jQuery autocomplete widget function based on variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

So to initialize autocomplete for a textbox, you do this `$('#textbox').autocomplete({...});`

I have a custom widget declared:

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", jQuery.ui.autocomplete, {
    ......
});
```

In this case the widget's name is `catcomplete`, so to initialize a custom autocomplete, you can do this: `$('#textbox').catcomplete({...});`

Now comes the tricky part. I'm trying to call `$('#textbox').catcomplete({...});` using a variable name, in this way:

```
var w = 'catcomplete';
//this is where i try to call the widget
$('#textbox').{w}({...}); // <-- this is obviously wrong
```

While the example is obviously wrong, but I hope it gives a generally good idea of what I'm trying to do. By the way the widget cannot be modified (legacy issues).

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code works to call jQuery.find method (get the first div inside the body):

```
$('body')['find']('div:first')
```

So, the solution for you should be something like this:

```
$('body')[yourVariable]({...})
```